# Huawei, listFiles() stop working (NullPointerException) after ugrading to Android Q

Tags: android, file, android-10.0, huawei-mobile-services

It is a Huawei P20, model EML-AL00, Build 10.0.0.156 (EMUI 10.0.0).

I had to upgrade the OS to the last version, Android 10. I delayed this until I could, aware of the danger, but it is annoyng to close an update popup every time you activate the device.

Now some apps are not opening, I discovered many errors, i.e., on API retrieving phone data, or retrieving file information,

```
final String rootPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/";
File f = new File(path); // path, e.g., /storage/emulated/0/
File[] files = f.listFiles();
```

returns `null` on this phone (and only on this phone). I'd like to solve this.

Anybody found any reason why? Permission are declared and granted, I repeat, it seems to be an issue / bug / "feature" of this phone.

Answer (score 0):

Skip the trailing slash. It's a bug on some systems (including Samsung if I recall correctly).

Comment: Not easy as that unfortunately, it is one of the things I tried, placing all trailing slashes one by one.

Comment: listFiles() returns null for that path on Android 10. Check for null before use. Or better dont use that path.